# how to design for all device resolution

Tags: android

hi all
i have to use linear layout with all resolution type device such as 480x800,480x854,320x480.
i use x,y position for placing element in linear layout while designing for 320x480. i have to redesign  for other resolution device therefore it takes more time. please give common method for all the resolution with linear layout. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DON'T design for a specific resolution. Use combinations of `layout_weight` attributes, `layout_width` and `layout_height` values of `wrap_content` and `match_parent` to get different proportional widths depending on the screen size, rather than hard coding pixel values.

For example, say you want to add a row of four buttons, each taking up equal width, along the top of the screen, offset from the top left by ~5 pixels:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:text="Button 1"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:text="Button 2"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:text="Button 3"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:text="Button 4"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you a reliable result for any screen density, and you never have to worry about a certain pixel value. The use of dp (device-independent pixel) for the padding also changes slightly depending on the density, so that it stays a consistent physical size no matter what the resolution.

Read through the examples on the [Android Developers site](http://developer.android.com/) about LinearLayouts, FrameLayouts, and RelativeLayouts. You'll get a good feel on what each one is good for, and their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

You can define different layouts for different screen categories. So you can adapt your layout so that it fits the actual screen. A good resource that describes how this is done is available here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use density-independent pixel (dp) in layouts. And I think this could be helpful: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

Very EXCELLENT ANSWERS ... I believe that alot of individuals and business alike think that Android is a "Device" and not clearly understanding Android is a "OS". Inorder to properly display images for all devices running Android OS one must go with the option to Support Mutiple Devices and develop according to Android OS and not a certain device running Android OS. I have encountered this problem before, my Boss (at that time) said "What size Images does your Test Device need? I said "just get me the images! I was forced to use 320x480 images (according to the test device) and when the Regional Manager saw the demo product on his ThinkPad (and 4 other device's) I was terminated from my position because my Supervisor thought Android was a Device and Not a OS ... and the company Android App has yet to be completed.**My opinion** holds "**Supporting Mutiple Devices is developing for General Android OS** while **developing according to "Resolution" is for a certain device or type of device.**

Comment: thanks i got same problem and solved with supported for some devices. Have you get position(job)?

Comment: I got the position by being at the right place and speaking at the right time. But in the end with Development you have to either know what to do, where to go or who to ask ... Like this **great network of people here at Stackoverflow**.